# Vertica Large Objects

Tags: large-data, vertica, flextable

I am migrating a table from Oracle to Vertica that contains an LOB column. The maximum actual size of the LOB column amounts to 800MB. How can this data be accommodated in Vertica? Is it appropriate to use the Flex Table?

In Vertica's documentation, it says that data loaded in a Flex table is stored in column *raw* which is a LONG VARBINARY data type. By default, it has a max value of 32MB, which, according to the documentation can be changed(i.e. increased) using the parameter FlexTablesRawSize.

I'm thinking this is the approach for storing large objects in Vertica. We just need to update the FlexTablesRawSize parameter to handle 800MB of data. I'd like to consult if this is the optimal way or if there's a better way. Or will this conflict with Vertica's table row constraint limitation that only allows up to 32MB of data per row?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Vertica for what it's built for - running a Big Data database, you would, like in any analytical database, try to avoid large objects in your table. BLOBs and CLOBs are usually used to store unstructured data: large documents, image files, audio files, video files. You can't filter by such a column, you can't run functions on it, or sum it, etc, you can't group by it.

A safe and performant design should lead to storing the file name in a Vertica table column, storing the file maybe even in Hadoop, and letting the front end (usually a BI tool, and all BI tools support that) retrieve the file to bring it to a report screen ...

Good luck ...

Marco